# C# ASP.NET - Use method from another class to create labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a simple web page with some textboxes and buttons. When I click one of the buttons, I want some labels to appear below and display some info.

This works perfectly so long as I have all the methods within the _Default class. However, what I really need is for all this stuff to be inside a wrapper class. I have created the wrapper class with all the other methods I need for what I'm doing, and everything works just great except for the labels. They don't show. It isn't a problem with the code itself because the identical code works within the _Default class. It isn't the class itself because the other methods from that class work fine within the _Default class. So it seems to be something specific about labels-in-other-classes that I can't figure out. Is there some inheritance issue with controls across classes?

I just have a simple method within the wrapper class which creates labels:

```
     public void createLabels(string labelName)
     {
       Label label_Name = new Label();
       label_Name.ID = "label_Name";
       label_Name.Text = labelName;
       Controls.Add(label_Name);
       Label get_Name = new Label();
       get_Name.ID = "get_Name";
       get_Name.Text = "Not found";
       Controls.Add(get_Name);
     }
```

Then inside the _Default class, I call this method like,

```
MyWrapperClass abc = new MyWrapperClass();
abc.createLabels("asdf");
```

I'm guessing the issue lies with the "Controls.Add" but I cannot find what the correct way is.

Comment: Best practice would be to pass the reference of Label component as argument.

Comment: How are you declaring and initializing your wrapper class's `Controls` property? The obvious way would be to pass the page's `Controls` collection to your wrapper's constructor, but you're not showing that code here so it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass parent control as a parameter to `createLabels`:

```
public class MyWrapperClass 
{
  ...
  public void createLabels(Control parent, string labelName)
  {
    Label label_Name = new Label();
    label_Name.ID = "label_Name";
    label_Name.Text = labelName;
    parent.Controls.Add(label_Name);

    Label get_Name = new Label();
    get_Name.ID = "get_Name";
    get_Name.Text = "Not found";
    parent.Controls.Add(get_Name);
  }
}

MyWrapperClass abc = new MyWrapperClass();
abc.createLabels(this, "asdf");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Sherlock there is a checkmark to left of the answer, that can be clicked to stress the message in your comment :)

Comment: I'm not able to click it because I don't have enough points or whatever.

Comment: @Sherlock not the up/down arrows, but the "gray checkmark"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add to controls inside wrapper class. But Page object is not available in your wrapper class.

You can just return a Label from your wrapper class and add it to controls in main class.

```
public Label createLabels(string labelName)
 {
   Label label_Name = new Label();
   label_Name.ID = "label_Name";
   label_Name.Text = labelName;
   return label_Name;
 }
```

Then inside the _Default class, you call this method like,

```
MyWrapperClass abc = new MyWrapperClass();
Page.Controls.Add(abc.createLabels("asdf"));
```